# ajax value pass but no output

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a textarea. User type one/more letter presses tab. Ajax is called to display a select box based on textarea input.

```
<body>
    <textarea  id='test' name="test"></textarea>
    <div id="selectbox"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('test').onkeydown = function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                this.value += "    ";
                if(e.preventDefault) {
                    var search = document.getElementsByName('test')[0].value;
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "nishaone.php",
                    data: "search=" +search,
                    success: function(msg){
                            $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings){
                                $("#selectbox").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

I check the ajax coding. The values passed. all looks fine. Here is my php file I am using.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])&& $_POST['search']){
    echo $_POST['search'];

    echo '<select  name="plid" id="plid">';
    echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select the Pack Name--</option>';
    $tempholder = array();

    $query = "SELECT acname FROM glmast WHERE acname LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) ."%' ORDER BY acname ";
    $done=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($done);   
    for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++){
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($done);
        if (!in_array($r['acname'], $tempholder)){
            $tempholder[$i] = $r['acname'];
            echo "<option value='$r[acname]'>".$r["acname"]."</option>";
        }
    }

}
```

So this is my sql query output.

I tried without the if condition. It works great.

The post values also passes. But the output is a blank select box with no values in it.

Any idea?? As always any help is highly appreciated! Thanks..

Comment: Please make your code more readable.

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım edited :) .. The code looks fine. The post value is passed.. The ajax works and display the selectbox if I use some random data on my own.. Any idea??

Comment: You don't have problem with ajax whats returning from server? Can you console.log(msg) are getting correct answer

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım I get a blank selectbox with no values.. Just select the pack Item Id hing..That's all.. I guess it has somethin to do with mysql.. but even the query works fine when i use! No idea what is the problem.. Any idea..btw thanks for your time!!

Comment: I created a jsfiddle i think it was what you looking, can you check and tell me what you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30220/discussion-between-user2234992-and-utku-yildirim)

Answer (score 2):

I created an jsfiddle example about page side

http://jsfiddle.net/utku/cVeLh/3/

Can you change ajax query like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "nishaone.php",
    data: {search: search},
    success: function (msg) {

        // We assume you get "<option>something</option>" output from server
        $("#selectbox").append(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replyin!! But no effect :( ..

Comment: this is my output from server.. <select  name="plid" id="plid"><option value="" selected="selected">--Select the Pack Name--</option></select>

Comment: Did you check fiddle ?